# How Can I get NSStrings containing any character into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, nsstring, character

I let users write and then post what they have written to my MYSQL database, using PHP.  I have been sending the strings as URLs and then $_GET['string'] in the php and then putting them in the database.  I always have to take care of the spaces in the string by replacing them with %20.  And then I had to replace all kinds of different characters on top of that in order for the URLs to work.  This is a losing battle and the users expect their strings to be saved but if they contain a character I have not thought of, this will not be the case.  I have even tried sending along the strings as NSData in a POST but that did not seem to save the strings either.

How can I be sure the users' strings will save, no matter what crazy characters they type?

Thanks,
R

Comment: Okay thanks!  I will - but still sometimes it still doesn't save using post, like if I type the Euro symbol... It doesn't go through

Comment: What does the Euro symbol look like when saved in the database?

Comment: If I type a € in the db, it works fine a looks right.  I am discovering that it gets messed up before it goes to the php. The NSData shows nothing if there in a € in the NSString. I am encoding with NSASCIIStringEncoding but perhaps this is not what I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your data using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` before sending it to the server, and always use POST to send data to the server instead of GET. Also, it's a good idea to stop using ASCII altogether and to replace it with [Unicode](http://unicode.org) wherever you use strings. UTF-8 is a very convenient and compact Unicode encoding.